# Difference in delivery of special char via HTML page over SSL. Encoding rules?

Tags: html, iis-7, ssl, encoding

When dishing out HTML having a special character like half fraction

```
<li>½ tsp salt</li>  [HTTP]
```

it shows fine over HTTP. We are not explicitly encoding it as we should be: `&#38;`

However, the same HTML, when delivered over an SSL connection reveals the character as garbled with question marks in the source (using same browser) like so:

```
<li>?? tsp salt</li>  [HTTPS]
```

Despite the fact that we should be encoding these entities properly, this is not what the question is about ( we know how to solve that problem ).

Can anybody explain how the SSL encoding works such that there's a difference in delivery of the same special character over HTTP vs HTTPS, in the same browser?

More Info:

- We're using IIS7 and a certificate from GeoTrust.
- Any browser can be used to show the difference in SSL mode vs standard HTTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL won't make any difference here. The problem may be coincident with the use of SSL, but it isn't SSL that is causing the problem.

Comment: Interesting. Then it looks like I should work on extracting the smallest possible test case. There could be some programming in the system that runs only in SSL mode.

Comment: @John K - that would help narrow it down. I am assuming this HTML is dynamically generated. Have you tried some static HTML?

Comment: It turns out the page was being rewritten dynamically for SSL mode: "http://" replaced with "https://", and the chosen encoding was wrong.  Your answer helped direct us away from the assumption that SSL encryption was somehow a culprit, via a static HTML test.  The culprit was custom processing of our own that had been forgotten. Thanks.